# How do I render a varaible or data from the info.plist in VS code? (React-Native)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS code to build a react-native app in ios.

I know how to add a key into the info.plist file using Xcode, and I can now see that key displayed in my in my info.plist file in the VS filesystem but how do I access it to display the information on screen?

e.g SERVICE_KEY = "Hello World"

How do I get "Hello World" to be displayed on the screen using VS code not Xcode.

I'm thinking something like below but obviously it's incorrect

SERVICE_KEY is the key data I'm trying to show

````
```import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
// import 'info.plist';
// import 'strings.xml';

import {SERVICE_KEY} from 'rnFinal/ios/rnFinal/info.plist';


const Key = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View>
        {/* <Text>{SERVICE_KEY}</Text> */}
        <Text>I am going to be a key</Text>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Key;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});```
````

Below is the info.plist

````
``` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
//lots of key values...
    <key>Service_Key</key>
    <string>$(SERVICE_KEY)</string>
</dict>
</plist>```
````

Side question does anyone reccomend any good sources for building react native in VS code rather than using X'*every upgrade breaks*'Code?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access data from native side
What you can achieve this by Doing this in opposite way.

e.g: make a file here in js side and add keys there like

```
SERVICE_KEY="hello world"
```

and then use it in info.plist and in your js code aswell.

for detail understanding of this concept, have a look

[react-native-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-config)

Comment: So create the data like you in an env file and then give to the the plist file and wherever you want to display it? thanks buddy!

Comment: Please mark the answer correct if it resolve your issue :P